# ng-boilerPlate with a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, gruntjs

I am just starting out with AngularJS. I decided to go with ng-BoilerPlate as a structure.

I am currently stuck on creating a small custom directive.

What I did was the following :

I created an html file for the directive under src/app/login/sso/facebook-button.html.
This contains just regular code you need for a directive.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-block omb_btn-facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook visible-xs"></i>
    <span class="hidden-xs">Facebook</span>
</a>
```

In this same directory I also created the javascript file needed for this directive "ssoDirective.js".

```
app.directive('facebookButton', function() {
    return {
        restrict    : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'facebook-button.html'
    };
});
```

Finally I just used the template in a login.tpl.html file (which works no problem without this template).

```
<facebook-button><facebook-button>
```

Now when I grunt this code (just the normal grunt config of ng-boilerPlate) I get the following error in Chrome :

```
GET http://localhost:63342/app/login/sso/facebook-button.html 404 (Not Found)angular.js:8632 
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /app/login/sso/facebook-button.html
```

I understand why this error is arrising. When I look into the build directory the facebook-button.html file just isn't there anywhere. Using grep I can also not find the contents of this file anywhere in this directory.
So grunt clearly skips this file while building.

So the question is. How do you create a very simple directive like this in ng-boilerPlate. Where do you place the .html for a directive so it gets included in the grunt build of ng-boilerPlate, and what templateUrl you specify so it gets found.

Answer (score 1):

The templates in [**ngbp**](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) will be ***merged*** into one file during the build process (actually two separate files, `templates-app.js` for the app-modules and `templates-common.js` for common reusables). This process done by [**html2js**](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) task configured in `Gruntfile.js`.

In `build.config.js` you can specify which files where to merge. By default all files match `src/common/**/*.tpl.html` pattern goes to `templates-common.js` and files match `src/app/**/*.tpl.html` merged into `templates-app.js`. You can also add your own rules but don't forget to configure `Gruntfile.js` as well!

If you really want to use explicit template definition (so the template will not be merged into `build/templates-app` or `build/templates-common.js`) one solution is to use the `template` property on your directive and provide the template inline. A better way to achieve the same is to use `$templateCache` to include template.

*Refering to the [documentation of $templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)*

First you must configure the `run()` section of your module as the following:

```
app.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('facebook-button.html', 'Content of facebook-button.html');
});
```

Now you can use the standard `templateUrl` way to include `facebook-button.html` into your directive!

```
app.directive('facebookButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict    : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'facebook-button.html'
  };
});
```

You can get cleaner code if you separate the function and give just reference to `run()`

```
(function(){

  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('app',[...])
    .run(Template);
    .directive('facebookButton',Directive);

  function Directive(){
    return {
      restrict    : 'E',
      templateUrl : 'facebook-button.html'
    };
  }

  function Template($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('facebook-button.html', 
      '...'+
      'Content of facebook-button.html'+
      '...'
    );
  }
})();
```